# Test Question Repetition (probability)

Tags: probability

I have  a test bank of 150 questions and 40 students and each will have a test consisting of 15 question. How can I estimate how many times a question will be repeated?

Thank you all

Comment: Hint: what's the probability a specific question will appear before one student? Then use linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of questions administered is $40(15) = 600$. Then, because the situation is symmetric with respect to each question, we can expect each question to be repeated $\frac{600}{150} = \boxed{4}$ times.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!